# Delete all rows below "Adjustments" using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data regarding benefits. At the bottom of these worksheets are adjustments. These should not be used in my Macros and formulas.

Instead of manually deleting, I'd like VBA to find "Adjustments" and delete that row and all rows below this. I have 3 worksheets I needs to this to repeat on.

I've googled and tried various codes but cannot seem to get it to read properly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

First step is to find the first row of your Adjustments.  You'll use .Find method to get that.  Below is a sample line of code.  You can google for more details and examples.

Once you have that, you'll find the last row, and then delete rows from start of adjustment rows to last row.  I've included functions below that should help.

```
Set foundCell = rng.Cells.Find(varSearchValue, celStartCell, enuXlFindLookIn, enuXlLookAt)

Public Function LastUsedRow(wks As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wks.UsedRange   ' Excel will recalc used range
    LastUsedRow = rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count - 1
End Function

Public Sub DeleteRows(wks As Worksheet, lngRowStart As Long, Optional ByVal lngRowEnd As Long = 0)
    If lngRowEnd = 0 Then lngRowEnd = lngRowStart
    wks.Rows(lngRowStart & ":" & lngRowEnd).Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've inferred that *Adjustments* is some sort of sub-level header row label. I'll assume that it is always in column A.

```
sub ScrubAdjustments()

  dim w as long, wss as variant, m as variant

  wss = array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3")

  for w = lbound(wss) to ubound(wss)
    with worksheets(wss(w))

      m = application.match("adjustments", .range("a:a"), 0)
      if not iserror(m) then
        .range(.cells(m, "A"), .cells(.rows.count, "A")).entirerow.delete
      end with

    end with
  next w

end sub
```